# User.Identity.Name is null after local login

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, .net-core-3.0

I configure `IdentityServer4` to use AspNet Identity (.net core 3.0) in order to allow users to authenticate (login/password).

My third application is an WebApi in `.net core 3.0`.

After logging, authentication and authorization succeeded but I can't retrieve UserId through User.Identity.Name which is null/empty.

However, I can see the claims information which contain a `sub` claim containing the userId.

Here is the packages I use for my IdentityServer4 web app

```
<PackageReference Include=&quot;IdentityServer4&quot; Version=&quot;3.0.1&quot; />
```

Comment: @DevanshiMishra I suppose he is trying to authenticate using jwt authenticaiton.

Comment: Why are you looking at the `Name` claim when you know the Id is available in the `sub` claim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm facing to the same issue and I found two solutions.

- **[Solution 1] - WebApi - Updating NameClaimType of IdentityServerAuthentication
  configuration**

In your startup file of your WebApi, update the NameClaimType property

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
         {
               options.CacheDuration = xxxxx;
               options.Authority = xxxxx;
               options.ApiName = xxxx;
               options.ApiSecret = xxxxx;
               options.RequireHttpsMetadata = xxxxxx;
               options.NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Subject;
         });
```

- **[Solution 2] - IdentityServer4 App - Creating new profil to customize your claims**

Create a new profil for IdentityServer4 server in order to customize claims inside the token.

```
public class AspNetIdentityProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> _claimsFactory;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public AspNetIdentityProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);

        var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();

        claims = claims.Where(claim => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(claim.Type)).ToList();

        claims.Add(new Claim("name", user.UserName));
        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);

        context.IsActive = user != null;
    }
}
```

In your startup file

```
services.AddTransient<IProfileService, AspNetIdentityProfileService>();
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for a claim that's already available. I wonder, if oidc uses the `sub` claim as identifier, why not use the `sub` claim? Is there an historical reason? Because I doubt that in oidc it's recommendable to use a `name` claim for an Id value. As it's clearly not a name, but more important, in oidc `name` is part of the `profile` identity claims. With this solution the UserInfo endpoint will return a token that contains two `name` claims (if available), the actual name and sub as name. Also note that GetProfileDataAsync is called multiple times with different contexts.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg, .net core 3.0, by default, IdentityServerAuthentication middleware uses `name` claim to set the User.Identity.Name property. I actually just update the NameClaimType to use `sub` claim. (just one line of code)

Comment: Yes, but name has nothing to do with the Id. So why put the Id in the name claim? That's what makes no sense to me, especially since the sub claim is available. And with the _lot of code_ remark I was obviously referring to the second solution in your answer.

Comment: My second solution is a sample. update it as well as you want. what i'm saying is that `name` claim is not set by the identity server delivered by the quickstart project of IDS4.

Comment: That's because that's not how the oidc implementation of IdentityServer works. By default there are no Identity claims in the _access token_, and the _identity token_ only contains the sub claim. For additional information the _client_ has to access the UserInfo endpoint (using the access token) to request user information, like name. The Api actually has no access to this information, and why should it? There is no UI to show the name. If it is needed as part of a request, then it should be added to the contents of the request.